# How to check for something 1 day old or newer with a Time object? (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, datetime, date, time

How do I check if the current Time object is at AT MOST 1 day old. I only want to store it to the database if its 24 hours old or newer. if it makes it easier I would also accept anything "yesterday" regardless of the current time. As soon as it switches to the next day "yesterday" changes as well, so at MOST it would be 47 hours and 59 minutes.

The time format I have is: 2011-12-16 17:44:01 -0800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Time
    def older_than_day?; Time.new - 86400 > self end
end

p Time.new("2000-1-1 00:00:00 -0800").older_than_day?
# => true
p Time.new.older_than_day?
# => false
```

Answer (score 0):

*Slightly* more readable: if you're using Rails (which you *might* be, since you mention databases), you can use the `day` method to write it like this...

```
class Time
    def older_than_day?; (Time.new - 1.day) > self end
end
```

In fact, using `day` makes it so easy to read that I might not bother to define a method.  I might just write code like this in-place...

```
if myTime > (Time.now - 1.day)
  doSomething
else
  doSomethingElse
end
```